# Winston log files not always saved while using process.exit() - node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, process, winston

I cannot understand this concept... while using process.exit() on a program that saves log files to the console and to a actual file, the log events are all printed out in the console but only the first one (or none at all) are saved into the file. Here is a quick demo of the issue:

In the code below, a winston logger is create. Then in the numberScore function, for each number in the array I create a log, and at the end I log all of the events in parallel - just a demo!

```
var async = require('async')
var winston = require('winston')
var moment = require('moment')

var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
  transports: [
    new (winston.transports.Console)({
      timestamp: function () {
        return moment().format('D/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss:SSS')
      },
      colorize: true
    }),
    new (require('winston-daily-rotate-file'))({
      filename: 'logs/-system.log',
      datePattern: 'dd-MM-yyyy',
      prepend: true,
      json: false,
      timestamp: function () {
        return moment().format('D/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss:SSS')
      }
    })
  ]
})


var values = [1,2,3,4,5]

var numbersScore = function(done) {
var array = []
    array.push(function(callback) {
        logger.info('test1')
        callback()
      })

values.forEach(function(number){
    number += 1 
    console.log(number)


    array.push(function(callback) {
        logger.info('test2', number)
        callback()
      })
})

async.parallel(array, function(error, data){
    console.log('done')
    process.exit()
})
}
numbersScore()
```

The above code when run prints out this in the console - which means everything works great - however in the log file nothing is saved.

```
2
3
4
5
6
28/09/2016 10:57:45:911 - info: test1
28/09/2016 11:01:22:677 - info: Numbers are 2
28/09/2016 11:01:22:678 - info: Numbers are 3
28/09/2016 11:01:22:678 - info: Numbers are 4
28/09/2016 11:01:22:678 - info: Numbers are 5
28/09/2016 11:01:22:678 - info: Numbers are 6
done
```

As soon as you comment out `process.exit()` the log file is saved correctly with all the required data. HOWEVER.... in my scenario I need to have process.exit() - so whats the workaround?

**What I have tried:**

1. Using Winston callback - https://github.com/winstonjs/winston#events-and-callbacks-in-winston - fails
2. Adding setTimeout - fails (process.exit does not seem to wait for the setTimeout - it exits the program anyways)
3. As you can see in the example above, using async.parallel however still no luck

Any other solutions for this?

*The same issue is open on github -https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/issues/228 - however no solution that fully works has been identified yet.*

Comment: The github issue you linked to does have a workaround proposed by Kegsay. Listening to the internal `_stream`, and listen to the `finish` event.

Answer (score 0):

From the [github issue](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/issues/228):

*Note: This is a copy-paste of the relevant section of the issue, written by the user Kegsay.*

For what it's worth, you can get around the use of `setTimeout` but you need to grab the underlying `_stream`:

```
// log then exit(1)
logger.error("The thing to log", function(err) {
  var numFlushes = 0;
  var numFlushed = 0;
  Object.keys(logger.transports).forEach(function(k) {
    if (logger.transports[k]._stream) {
      numFlushes += 1;
      logger.transports[k]._stream.once("finish", function() {
        numFlushed += 1;
        if (numFlushes === numFlushed) {
          process.exit(1);
        }
      });
      logger.transports[k]._stream.end();
    }
  });
  if (numFlushes === 0) {
    process.exit(1);
  }
});
```

As mentioned above, use of the callback function alone is not sufficient to get it to have flushed correctly to file. This feels like a bug to me.

Note that I'm actually listening for the finish event: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_finish rather than using winston's flush or closed event because that too is insufficient to get it to log correctly :/

Comment: I did see that, however I am not sure how to implement it into my code, bearing in mind that process.exit() is not called inside the logs - there are other functions running which depend on process.exit(). So this solution does not work for me

Comment: This does not provide a answer to the question asked... You already posted this in the comment

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, it worked for me (based on Winston):

```
logger.on('logging', function (transport, level, msg, meta) {
  if (msg == "equal your message" && transport.name == "file") {
    var id = setInterval(function () {
      //when it is done to write the file, it will enter the id condition
      if (transport._stream._writableState.bufferedRequestCount==0) {
        exitProcess(0);
      }
    },1000)
  }
});
```