# Uncaught Exceptions Not Logged in Winston-MongoDB Logger

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, error-handling, winston

I'm encountering an issue where uncaught exceptions in my Node.js application are not being properly logged using the Winston-MongoDB logger. Below is the relevant code snippet and logger configuration I'm using:

```
// This is how I'm handling uncaught exceptions
process.on("uncaughtException", (ex) => {
  logger.error(ex.message, ex);
  process.exit(1);
});

// This is my logger configuration
const { createLogger, format, transports } = require("winston");
require("winston-mongodb");

const logger = createLogger({
  transports: [
    new transports.File({
      filename: "logfile.log",
      format: format.combine(format.timestamp(), format.json()),
    }),
    new transports.MongoDB({
      db: "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/vidly",
      level: "info",
      options: { useUnifiedTopology: true },
      collection: "log",
      format: format.combine(format.timestamp(), format.json()),
    }),
  ],
});

module.exports = logger;
```

In my initial setup, uncaught exceptions were not being logged to either the MongoDB database or the log file. However, when I added a setTimeout before calling process.exit(1), the logger started working properly:

```
process.on("uncaughtException", (ex) => {
  logger.error(ex.message, ex);
  setTimeout(() => {
    process.exit(1);
  }, 500);
});
```

Is using a setTimeout before calling process.exit(1) a recommended solution for this issue? Or is there a better approach to ensure that the logger has time to complete its operations before the application exits?

I appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to handle uncaught exceptions with the Winston-MongoDB logger in a more effective way. Thank you!

Comment: Did you try to setup the logger as write in the [documentation](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston-mongodb)? For `db` it uses a connection promise instead of a connection uri string.

Comment: It seems to be a generic problem of winston logger and not specific to Mongo driver. See [Winston log files not always saved while using process.exit()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39744376/winston-log-files-not-always-saved-while-using-process-exit-node-js) or https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/issues/1629 and https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/issues/1504

Comment: This [winston-log-and-exit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston-log-and-exit) looks like a simple solution.